# Converting images to MNIST format

Tags: python

I have problem with using the python script. I have an issue I can't resolve. 
Generally I found it on Git. It suposed to be working. Below there is part of the script.
Variable folder is a path to folder with 14 subfolders.

```
def get_labels_and_files(folder, number=0):
    # Make a list of lists of files for each label
    filelists = []
    subdir = get_subdir(folder)
    for label in range(0, len(subdir)):
        filelist = []
        filelists.append(filelist)
        dirname = os.path.join(folder, subdir[label])
        for file in os.listdir(dirname):
            if (file.endswith('.png')):
                fullname = os.path.join(dirname, file)
                if (os.path.getsize(fullname) > 0):
                    filelist.append(fullname)
                else:
                    print('file ' + fullname + ' is empty')
        # sort each list of files so they start off in the same order
        # regardless of how the order the OS returns them in
        filelist.sort()

    # Take the specified number of items for each label and
    # build them into an array of (label, filename) pairs
    # Since we seeded the RNG, we should get the same sample each run
    labelsAndFiles = []
    for label in range(0, len(subdir)):
        count = number if number > 0 else len(filelists[label])
        filelist = random.sample(filelists[label], count)
        for filename in filelist:
            labelsAndFiles.append((label, filename))

    return labelsAndFiles


def make_arrays(labelsAndFiles, ratio):
    global height, width
    images = []
    labels = []
    imShape = imageio.imread(labelsAndFiles[0][1]).shape
```

Error message:

```
C:\PROGRAMOWANIE\Python_OCR\Convert-own-data-to-MNIST-format-master\Convert-own-
data-to-MNIST-format-master>python convert_to_mnist_format.py C:\PROGRAMOWANIE\P
ython\OCR_Math\training_images 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "convert_to_mnist_format.py", line 215, in 
main(sys.argv)
File "convert_to_mnist_format.py", line 199, in main
labelsAndFiles, argv[2])
File "convert_to_mnist_format.py", line 115, in make_arrays
imShape = imageio.imread(labelsAndFiles[0][1]).shape
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could someone wiser then me look at this and say what's wrong with it, please.

Comment: Please don't link to the external resources, edit your question and post the issue (along the minimal code that triggers error) here.

Comment: The ´labelsAndFiles´ must have returned empty list or the list is not nested. Print out ´labelsAndFiles´ to verify it. If you have further problems please post the problems and outputs clearly. Cheers!